# Rails form redirecting to 'new' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What I am trying to do is build a form in which the user fills some of the fields for a new Publication, and takes you to the New Publication action, with those fields already filled in, so the user fills the rest.

I got the controller part covered, but I cant find how to use form_for for this, as its not exactly associated to the model (only some of the necessary fields are in the first form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do

`form_tag new_publication_path()`

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the best way to do this, but you can hide some of the fields in the form depending on whether the model id is valid. For example (in haml):

```
- if @model.id #only shows up if the model has been saved.
  = f.text_field :field_name, ...
```

This way you can use the usual new, and then when the model has been saved, just redirect to the 'edit' action and the rest of the fields show up.